# Postfix configuration? problem

Tags: configuration, postfix

I try to configure mail server on my VPS. I try [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-postfix-on-centos-6) but unfortunately I cant run it.
My configuration files are exact the same I only replaced mydomain.com with my own domain. Also when I put service status on postfix I receive master dead but pid file exists. I have tried to stop Postfix and start it again (with OK result) but status is same. Tried to google it but I dont find any info I could use.

Thanks for any advice.

My configuration files:
sudo vi /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
soft_bounce             = no
queue_directory         = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory       = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory        = /usr/libexec/postfix
mail_owner              = postfix

# The default_privs parameter specifies the default rights used by
# the local delivery agent for delivery to external file or command.
# These rights are used in the absence of a recipient user context.
# DO NOT SPECIFY A PRIVILEGED USER OR THE POSTFIX OWNER.
#
#default_privs = nobody

myhostname              = mail.adamlakomy.de 
mydomain                = adamlakomy.de

mydestination           = $myhostname, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

mynetworks_style        = host
mailbox_transport       = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp
local_destination_recipient_limit       = 300
local_destination_concurrency_limit     = 5
recipient_delimiter=+

virtual_alias_maps      = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

header_checks           = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks      = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks
smtpd_banner            = $myhostname

debug_peer_level        = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path           = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path         = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path              = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group            = postdrop
html_directory          = no
manpage_directory       = /usr/share/man
sample_directory        = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
readme_directory        = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable          = yes
smtpd_sasl_application_name     = smtpd
smtpd_recipient_restrictions    = permit_sasl_authenticated,
                                  permit_mynetworks,
                                  reject_unauth_destination,
                                  reject_invalid_hostname,
                                  reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
                                  reject_non_fqdn_sender,
                                  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
                                  reject_unknown_sender_domain,
                                  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                                  reject_unauth_pipelining,
                                  reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
                                  reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
                                  reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org,
                                  reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
                                  permit

smtpd_sasl_security_options     = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain         = 
broken_sasl_auth_clients        = yes

smtpd_helo_required             = yes
```

/etc/postfix/virtual

```
user@adamlakomy.de   user\@adamlakomy.de
```

/etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf

```
pwcheck_method: auxprop
auxprop_plugin: sasldb
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5
```

/etc/imapd.conf

```
virtdomains:        userid
defaultdomain:      adamlakomy.de
servername:     adamlakomy.de
configdirectory:    /var/lib/imap
partition-default:  /var/spool/imap
admins:         cyrus
sievedir:       /var/lib/imap/sieve
sendmail:       /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
hashimapspool:      true
allowanonymouslogin:    no
allowplaintext:     yes
sasl_pwcheck_method:    auxprop
sasl_mech_list:     CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 PLAIN
tls_cert_file:      /etc/pki/cyrus-imapd/cyrus-imapd.pem
tls_key_file:       /etc/pki/cyrus-imapd/cyrus-imapd.pem
tls_ca_file:        /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

autocreatequota:        -1
createonpost:           yes
autocreateinboxfolders:     spam
autosubscribeinboxfolders:  spam
```

Comment: Try looking in `/var/log/mail*` or whatever log for errors?

Comment: there is no log file at all only statistics file with some gibberish when I open it in nano